# Databricks file copy with dbtuils only if file doesn't exist

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using the following databricks utilites (`dbutils`) command to copy files from one location to another as shown below:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('adl://dblake.azuredatalakestore.net/jfolder2/thisfile.csv','adl://cadblake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/')
```

However, I want the file to be copied over only if no such file with the same name '`thisfile.csv`' exists.

Can someone let me know whether is that possible?

If not, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[dbutils.fs.ls()](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html) lists files in the given path.

[image: ls]

So you can check if `thisfile.csv` exists before copying the file:

```
if "thisfile.csv" not in [file.name for file in dbutils.fs.ls("adl://cadblake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/")]:
    dbutils.fs.cp("adl://dblake.azuredatalakestore.net/jfolder2/thisfile.csv", "adl://cadblake.azuredatalakestore.net/landing/")
```